# Selecting other elements with a same class name and not this perticular element

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I am trying to select images with same class name and exclusing a single image with an id.
I am quite confused here.
how should I do this
Here are my bunch of images

```
 <li><img id="firstImage" class="fullBg anim" src="img/1.jpg"></li>
  <li><img id="secondImage" class="fullBg anim" src="img/2.jpg"></li>  
  <li><img id="thirdImage" class="fullBg anim" src="img/3.jpg"></li>
  <li><img id="fourthImage" class="fullBg anim" src="img/4.jpg"></li>            
  <li><img id="fifthImage" class="fullBg anim" src="img/5.jpg"></li>
  <li><img id="sixthImage" class="fullBg anim" src="img/6.jpg"></li>
  <li><img id="seventhImage" class="fullBg anim" src="img/7.jpg"></li>
  <li><img id="eigthImage" class="fullBg anim" src="img/8.jpg"></li>
```

Now If i have to select the `#secondImage` image and do something to the rest images with  a class name `fullBg` how to do it. please help, thanks.

Comment: `$('img.fullBg').not('#secondImage')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So bascially the most elegent way of doing this is creating a class and putting all the added stuff to it.
And then do this

```
    $('img.anim').not('#secondImage').addClass('yourClass');
```

That way the code would be more optimised.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not()` method in jQuery, to add class use `addClass()`

*Example :*

```
$('img.anim').not('#secondImage').addClass('fullBg');
```

The above example will select all `img` tag having class `anim` except the `img` tag having id `secondImage`

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $(".fullbg:not('#secondImage')").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
   });
});
```